# Python BeautifulSoup does not print()

Tags: python, printing, error-handling, beautifulsoup

Following beautifulsoup script shows no output. Did i miss anything?
It was intended to hit some of the prints.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

url1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APmUWC8S1_M"

def getTitle(url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    return bsObj

    title = getTitle(url1)

    if title == None:
        print("None at URL: " + url1)
    else:
        print(title)
```

Comment: Please check your indentation - should the line after `return bsObj` be at the same indentation level? Because right now, you're always returning before you print anything besides the `HTTPError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT:

You problem is finally... identation.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

url1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APmUWC8S1_M"

def getTitle(url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    return bsObj

title = getTitle(url1)

if title == None:
    print("None at URL: " + url1)
else:
    print(title)
```

#### Old answer

Your problem is that `return bsObj` prevent the function to execute the `print`s. The only thing your function can print is a `HTTPError` or an `ArgumentError`.

If you want to return `bsObj`, you need it to return it at the end of the function, because `return` exit the function.

Oh, and you inconditionally recurse the function, so anyway it will StackOverflow.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

url1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APmUWC8S1_M"

def getTitle(url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None

    title = getTitle(url1) # Infinite recursion

    if title == None:
        print("None at URL: " + url1)
    else:
        print(title)
    return bsObj # Moved to the end
```

Answer (score 1):

For BeautifulSoup4, I would reccommend using the requests module (obtained via pip), for getting the website data.

To get the html of the desired site, use

```
content = requests.get(url).content
```

That will save the entire html doc to the variable "content".

From that, you can get use the following script to print out any data you need.

Note: lxml (the html parser that is good for bs4) has problems when installing in python 3, so 2.7 is the best version for this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def getTitle(url):
    content = requests.get(url).content
    page = bs(content, "lxml")
    title = page.title.string
    return title

url1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APmUWC8S1_M"
t = getTitle(url1)

if t == None:
    print "None at url " + url1
else:
    print t
```

I tested this on my local machine (Win 10, Python 2.7.12, requests, beautifulsoup4, and lxml installed via pip) and it worked perfectly.

If you want more information on requests, you can look [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), and more info for BeautifulSoup can be found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Hope that this has helped you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! People are awesome. This is why i love stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jacs no problem, happy to help.

Comment: Let me think a while on both answers and i will give you a more in-deep feedback.

Comment: @Jacs I found a way to do it on Python 3.5, it takes a small amount of downloading and command line stuff but it's not hard if you're interested.

Comment: @RedXTech Thank you guys for the help! It's working fine now. It was a indentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys


def getContent(url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    return bsObj

url1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5NeyI4-fdI"
content = getContent(url1)
if content == None:
    print("Conent could not be found at URL: " + url1)
else:
    print(content)
```